# Matrix optimization problem for sparseness and closeness.

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, soft-question, nonlinear-optimization, signal-processing

If I have a matrix $${\bf M}= \left[\begin{array}{l}{\bf M_k+\epsilon}\\{\bf M_u}\end{array}\right], \cases{{\bf M_k} \text{ known}\\{\bf M_u} \text{ unknown}}$$

How can I then find $\bf \epsilon$ (matrix) which is minimal (or regularized) in some norm and that $\bf M_u$ and $\bf M_k+\epsilon$ is sparse, ${\bf M}^{-1}$ exists and is also sparse?

Comment: Just to be clear, $M_{k}$ is fixed and $\epsilon$ and $M_{u}$ are variables to be optimized over, right?

Comment: @BrianBorchers Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a body of research on finding a sparse matrix that is an *approximate* inverse for a given matrix.  This is used to find an approximate inverse for a sample covariance matrix which typically isn't of full rank and thus doesn't have an exact inverse.

See for example:

[Sun, Tingni, and Cun-Hui Zhang. "Sparse matrix inversion with scaled lasso." The Journal of Machine Learning Research 14.1 (2013): 3385-3418.](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume14/sun13a/sun13a.pdf)

Let

$U=\left[
\begin{array}{c}
M_{k} \\
0
\end{array}
\right]
$

Then find a sparse matrix $V$ such that

$UV \approx I$.

Here "approximately" is measured by the spectral norm, $\| UV - I \|$. The $V$ matrix would then be your $M^{-1}$.

Note that although $UV$ is approximately $I$, this doesn't mean that $V^{-1}$ will be very close to $U$ or that $V^{-1}=M$ would necessarily be sparse.

Comment: Interesting. But this won't let us find $\bf M_u$, will it?

Comment: $\epsilon$ and $M_{u}}$ would be the difference between $V^{-1}$ and $M_{k}$.

Comment: But if I also want to put constraints on them? Is it handled in the paper?

Comment: As I wrote in the answer, this doesn't give you a way to constrain the sparsity of $\epsilon$ and $M_{u}$.